# Is it possible to have a GAE channel-API to iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-app-engine, channel-api

I want to try using channel-API between my GAE app and the iphone.
I'm not sure where to start... should I try it with UIWebView that runs a javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's possible on the iPhone. 
Of course, it should be on a different NSThread...
and it's a nightmare to debug because of the bad access to JS from the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using push notifications to tell the app to fetch the new data?

Comment: Yes I have, but then the idea fell. Push notifications are not real-time, and not reliable. I would only use them if I needed to fetch data on the background...

Answer (score 0):

A web view running the Channel API JS may work, but you probably want to use XMPP. See [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp.html) and try [this project](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone).

Comment: XMPP is unlikely to be the solution, since it would require the user to have a Google account just for the app.

Comment: XMPP seems like a way to do that, but only if I have no other way... I need to update the App after an event happend on the server. the message sent to the App contains one tiny parameter. XMPP for doing that seems a bit too much (from server CPU/cost point of view)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have some kind of app-in-the-middle native app that communicate with the channel's javascript